# react native inapp update - example of use

Tags: react-native

I can't choose between this two librairies for inapp updates:

`sp-react-native-in-app-updates` or `react-native-android-inapp-updates`
I can't find any example to use them well. their documentation is really not clear.

Please any suggestion with any example or tutorial since I am a beginner

Comment: Try appcenter codepush

Comment: I already use it and it works good but is not for the same reason.. in-app update is for a complete update installed from play store not for some javascript update